# Close Unedited Tabs in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to close all tabs in Eclipse that have no changes?  Thus leaving all the files I am currently editing as the only open tabs?

Ideally, "change" would be relative to source control, but relative to file system change date compared to editor session start would work as well.

Comment: Try to learn how to use Mylyn task list and the task context, it's invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does have a * marked before the file name, if it has unsaved changes. You can use that to identify the unsaved changes and proceed accordingly.

Comment: The * serves a different role, of indicating not saved to the local file system.  Save All solves that.

My problem is I will have 20 tabs/files open, but only 3 I have edits in, I want to close the other 17.  I can see the 3 I care about on the Synchronize pane, but that doesn't really make for a graceful way to close the others.

Comment: I am afraid, that option is not yet available in Eclipse, as you told just Synchronize pane is there.